# What would be the Regex to match a word wrapped in double brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find the correct regex syntax for matching and splitting on a word that is surrounded by double brackets.

```
const string originalString = "I love to [[verb]] while I [[verb]].";
```

I tried

```
var arrayOfStrings = Regex.Split(originalString,@"\[\[(.+)\]\]");
```

But it did not work correctly. I don't know what I am doing wrong

I would like the arrayOfStrings to come out like so

```
arrayOfStrings[0] = "I love to "
arrayOfStrings[1] = "[[verb]]"
arrayOfStrings[2] = " while I "
arrayOfStrings[3] = "[[verb]]"
arrayOfStrings[4] = "."
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that is what you need.

```
string input = "I love to [[verb]] while I [[verb]].";
string pattern = @"(\[\[.+?\]\])";

string[] matches = Regex.Split( input, pattern );

foreach (string match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Comment: This will remove the bracketed words, which is not what the user wants.

Comment: Cyborgx37, the brackets will not be removed. It will return exactly what Laurence Burke asked for.

Comment: You are correct. My mistake - clearly I have misunderstood the Regex.Split function. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error message when I attempt to remove my downvote.

Comment: +1 for a working solution. BTW, if you edit your answer, @Cyborgx37 will be able to remove his downvote.

Comment: +1 Aha - never knew this: [*"If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array."*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) Very interesting - by enclosing the pattern in parentheses, the matched text is included in the results.

Comment: Huh... I could have sworn that this was the first thing I tried, before delving into lookaheads, and that it didn't work for me.  It *does* work, though, and it's certainly a simpler answer than mine.

Comment: @Bobson - The trick is to include parentheses around the pattern. Apparently that will cause the Split function to include the matched text. I'm going to experiment with this feature.

Answer (score 3):

The answer which will produce exactly what you want is `@"(?=\[\[.*?\]\])|(?<=\]\])"`.

This has two parts to it, separated by the `|` "or" symbol.

`(?=\[\[.*?\]\])` will look for any symbol which is immediately followed by a `[[` some characters, and a `]]`, and split inbetween it and the `[`.

`(?<=\]\])` will look for any symbol which is immediately preceded by `]]` and split just after the `]`.

These are called "lookahead" and "lookbehind", and you can find more variants of them [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet).

Comment: +1 Though I think the more relevant name to use in this situation is "zero-width assertion".

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - I'd never heard that term before.  Good to know there's an official term for it!